# Adding .xml View dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to dynamically add views I created in an seperate .xml file (card.xml) into an existing `LinearLayout` (`MainLinLay`). The .xml contains for now two `TextViews`. The adding will occure after the `onCreate` method is finished. I only know how many views I will add, after the first MQTT message is received.

I have searched for a solution/answer for hours but I'm unable to find something.

When a MQTT message is received, I will create an object of a class:

```
@Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                if(connected && !busy){
                    busy = true;
                    if (startup){
                        if (mqttMessage.toString().contains("\"Online\":true")){
                            Log.w("Debug", "Message Online");
                            busy = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        else{
                            startup = false;
                            Log.w("Debug","createCards");
                            creatCards(mqttMessage.toString());
                            busy = false;
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        Log.w("Debug","update");
                        busy = false;
                        //update(mqttMessage.toString());
                    }
                }

            }

public void creatCards(String message){

    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(message);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("JSON_err", e);
    }
    String nTemp="";
    try {
        JSONObject jobjValues = jObject.getJSONObject("Values");
        JSONObject jobjMeta = jObject.getJSONObject("MetaData");
        Iterator<String> names = jobjValues.keys();
        Log.w("Debug",message);
        int i=0;

        while(names.hasNext()){
            String name = names.next();
            Log.w("Debug",name);
            //Log.w("Context",this.getApplicationContext().toString());
            Card card = new Card(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), name);
            cards.add(card);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("JSON_err", e);
    }


}
```

Then in the class:

```
package com.henne.xxyy.homeautomation;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Card  extends LinearLayout{

    View rootView;
    View View1;
    TextView name;
    TextView value;
    LinearLayout mainLinLay;


    public Card(Context context, String message) {
        super(context);
        init(context, message);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String message) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, message);
    }

    private void init(Context context, String message) {
        try{

            rootView = inflate(context, R.layout.card, this);
            View1 = inflate(context, R.layout.activity_home, null);
            name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            value = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Value);




            name.setText("Name1");
            value.setText("234");

            mainLinLay = (LinearLayout) View1.findViewById(R.id.mainLinLay);

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            mainLinLay.setLayoutParams(params);

            mainLinLay.addView(rootView);

            rootView.invalidate();
            mainLinLay.invalidate();
            View1.invalidate();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.w("class_ex",e);
        }
    }

    private void update(String message) {

    }


}
```

There is no error or exception thrown. The two added `TextViews` just don't show.

What am I missing? I hope I shared enough information.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You're using the wrong context for one.  Views need the Context of the Activity they will appear in, not the Application context.

Comment: Also, your card constructor makes no sense.  You create it.  YOu inflate the view you want into it-  ok.  But then you inflate another view named activity home?  And you poot the card into it?  You know that each time you call inflate it makes a NEW view right-  that funky code won't give you the view hierarchy of the Activity and insert it there.  So you're not actually inserting your card into the activity's vontent view, you're inserting it into some random view you inflated that will get garbage collected immeiately. because nothing uses it.

Comment: You really ought to split your view creation from your networking code.  The networking code should send a message to whomever wants to listen that it has new data.  The Activity should listen to that message and create the appropriate UI for the data downloaded.  And the UI has the data to do that, whereas the networking code doesn't, and shouldn't (deciding to change the UI shouldn't require you to change your network implementation).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I realize, I don't get the concept of UI creation quite yet. Can you give me a hint were to look at (beside the documentation)? So you say I should implement a listener for when a message arrives and then build the UI within the activity and don't use a seperate class?